# "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function" - Why am I getting this?

Tags: javascript, callback, runtime-error

I am trying to create a 'typewriter' effect in javascript where it gives the appearance of 'spelling out' and then 'deleting' words from an array. I have a 'spell' function that spells out each word, and I'd like to add a callback to a 'delete' function so that once the word is finished typing, it will start deleting.

However, I keep getting the following error when I try to attach the callback:

```
main.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
   at spell (main.js:35)
   at main.js:32
```

It is in reference to the second-to-last line in the following block of code:

```
// SPELL OUT WORD FUNCTION
function spell(x, callback, length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        wordBox.innerHTML += letterArray[wordLength - x];
        if (--x) spell(x);
    }, randTime);

    callback(length);       // <--- THIS IS THE ERROR
    }
```

I believe the error might also be arising from this code, where I am calling the 'spell' function, but I am not sure:

```
// CALL ADD WORD FUNCTION
spell(wordLength, remove, wordLength);
```

I have also attached the entire block of code below as well. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

```
const words = [
    'creator.'
];

// START TYPEWRITER ON LOAD
window.addEventListener('load', typewriter);

function typewriter() {

    // LOOP FOR EACH WORD IN ARRAY
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        const word = words[i];
        const wordLength = word.length;
        const letterArray = [];
        const wordBox = document.querySelector('#text');

        var timeArray = [500, 600, 700, 800];
        var randTime = timeArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * timeArray.length)];
        var deleteDelay = 300;
        var iterationDelay = 1000;


        // CREATE LETTER ARRAY
        for (let i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            letterArray.push(word.charAt(i));
        }

        // SPELL OUT WORD FUNCTION
        function spell(x, callback, length) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                wordBox.innerHTML += letterArray[wordLength - x];
                if (--x) spell(x);
            }, randTime);

            callback(length);
        }

        // DELETE LETTERS FROM WORD FUNCTION
        function remove(y) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const string = wordBox.textContent;
                const newString = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
                wordBox.textContent = newString;
                if (--y) remove(y);
            }, deleteDelay);
        }

        // CALL ADD WORD FUNCTION
        spell(wordLength, remove, wordLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're invoking `add(x)` but `add` accepts *three* arguments, the second of which is `callback`, so `callback` is not defined at that point.

Comment: `where I am calling the 'add' function` - yet, no such function exists in the code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX The question has been updated. He suddenly decided to rename the function.

Comment: sorry guys, just wanted to make it more obvious what the function's purpose was. I apologize for the confusion! (This is my first post).

Comment: @GaborSzekely No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow!